# I want to keep default values in regular expressions if pattern does not match

Tags: python-textfsm

I want to keep default values in regular expressions if the pattern does not match

```
Value LINK_GROUP_NAME (\S+)

Start
  ^ link-group ${LINK_GROUP_NAME}
```

Above is my python textfsm template. Here if my regular expression doesn't match then I want to keep the default value instead of discarding.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do that?